# Difference between tabular and array environment

Tags: tables, arrays

What is the difference between a tabular and an array environment? When should be used the former and when the latter?

Comment: `array` is for `math mode` and  cell contents will be typeset in math mode (` textstyle`by default) and `tabular` is for `text mode`.

Comment: @Bernard since that's the only difference I guess you should make it an answer:-)

Comment: One is normally used in text, the other in equations.

Comment: I agree that should be an answer. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - There's another important difference between `array` and `tabular`: the name (and default value) of the parameter that governs the intercolumn whitespace (`\tabcolsep` and `\arraycolsep`).

Comment: @Mico oh yes I always forget these things as they are the same by the time they get to my bits of code (the outer layer of `\tabular` just does a \let for tabcolsep etc, so the inner layer basically doesn't know if it is one or the other:-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `array` environment is for `math mode` and cell contents will be typeset in math mode (`textstyle`by default) and `tabular` is for `text mode`.

While array requires being in math mode, the `tabular` environment can be used in `math mode`, and its contents will be typeset in `text mode`. Inside an `array`, the p, m or b specifiers also switch cell contents to text mode.

Comment: The exception is that `p` columns are in text mode also in an `array`.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, of course, but I focused on the main stream of the question. I'll add it, though, as it can be explained in a few words.

Comment: @user257651: they said I was aggressive, because there's an anonymous downvoter, which gives no explanation of his downvotes, and that I dared call a ‘troll’.

Answer (score 38):

- Environments such as `tabular`, `tabular*`, `tabularx`, `tabulary`, and `longtable` -- hereafter, `tabular`-like environments -- should be used if much of the material they contain should be typeset in text mode. (Note that having numbers in a table does not automatically mean it's necessary to typeset the numbers in math mode.) The material formatted by the `l`, `c`, `r`, `p`, and `m` column types is expected to be in text mode.

  It is possible, of course, to have math-mode material in a `tabular`-like environment. You'll just need to encase the math material in `$` switches like you would in ordinary mode. You could also use a specialized column type -- such as the `D` column type of the `dcolumn` package and the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package -- that treats its contents as being in math mode by default. (For `D` and `S` columns, you'll need to provide overrides for material that should *not* be be typeset in math mode.)
- The `array` environment is meant to be used in a math environment, and LaTeX treats the contents of `l`, `c`, and `r` columns -- but not of `p` columns! -- as being in math mode *unless* you do something to override this setting. If most of the table's material is going to be in math mode, it's preferable to use an `array` instead of a `tabular`-like environment: if nothing else, you'll save yourself from having to type a lot of `$` sumbols!
- The amount of intercolumn whitespace in `tabular`-like environments is given by `2\tabcolsep`. For `array` environments, the respective parameter is called `\arraycolsep`. The default values of `\tabcolsep` and `\arraycolsep` in the main LaTeX document classes are `6pt` and `5pt`, respectively.
- There's a very important LaTeX package called [array](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array). Despite what its name might suggest, it provides all sorts of goodies for both `array` environments *and* `tabular`-like environments. Indeed, the `tabularx` package depends on and therefore automatically loads the `array` package.

Comment: Your answer is great and very detailed but I have chosen Bernard's answer as it was the first to answer my question. I really appreciate it and I have upvoted, thank you.