# General differences between array, table, tabular, tabularx, longtable, supertabular, longtabu, etc

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, supertabular, longtabu

What are the general differences between the various table environments that exist for LaTeX? By this I mean: What are their basic purposes? Which ones are the most important ones for new users? Which ones are more advanced and should only be used by advanced LaTeX users? Are there differences in terms of the appearance of the table? How does the `booktabs` package play into this?

In short, where will you use each of them and what are merits and disadvantages of each of them. This question is especially useful to LaTeX newcomers, for whom the number of options can seem overwhelming.

Comment: For starters, see the posting [Difference between tabular and array environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204838/5001).

Comment: Sounds a bit too broad, it almost requires to dump the whole documentation about each in the answer! Could you focus on one specific aspect? For example just "purpose" or "spacing flexibility"...

Comment: I've voted for too broad. Some of those packages are mutually exclusive for different purposes.

Comment: When there is such a nice answer to this question, why do you want to put it on hold

Comment: See also [Differences between longtable and xtab](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113216/differences-between-longtable-and-xtab).

Comment: While this question is broad, it's not _too_ broad, because, well, people are faced with this question exactly.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The difference between `array` and `tabular` is discussed formally in [Difference between `tabular` and `array` environment](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/204838/5764), but I'll reference it here as well:

- `array` is probably the fundamental `tabular` structure in TeX that allows for stacking thing horizontally and vertically. You don't need to include the [`array` package](//ctan.org/pkg/array) in order to use an `array`. The package merely adds functionality to column specifications.
- `tabular` is a text version of `array`.

There is also a starred version `tabular*` that takes a length as an additional argument, as in

```
    \begin{tabular*}{<len>}[<vpos>]{<colspec>}

    \end{tabular*}
```

The `tabular*` is made to fit `<len>` horizontally. It's often used in conjunction with a `@{\extracolsep{<width>}}` in the `<colspec>` (typically where `<width>` is `\fill`) to spread out columns within `<len>`.

See also `tabularx` below.

- `table` is a float and has no concept of what is contained within it. While most people place a `tabular`-like structure inside a floating `table`, it can contain virtually anything. Placement of floats can be tricky, but this is covered in detail in [How to influence the position of float environments like `figure` and `table` in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5764). In contrast to this, `array`s and `tabular`s are placed as-is in the text, at the position they are coded.
- [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) is a package that extends the starred version `tabular*` - which requires a length to be specified - through the addition of an `X`-column. This new column type stretches out the `tabular` so that it fits within the specified fixed-width boundary. It avoids the user trying to figure out what width a `p`-column should be so that the resulting `tabular` width fits within some fixed boundary.

  The following example aims to highlight the above, resulting in two similar tables:

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{| p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-1.5\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep} 
                  | p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-1.5\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep} |}
    A & B
  \end{tabular}

  \medskip

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X | X |}
    A & B
  \end{tabularx}
  ```

  [image]
- [`longtable`](//ctan.org/pkg/longtable) provides a mixed-use case for having a too-large table that you want to split across the page boundary. Somewhat similar to wanting a non-floating `table` environment (in other words, having a `\caption`) but also allows the table to span multiple pages. That's a definite advantage, since page breaking comes with the bonus that column headers could be repeated automatically. It may require multiple compilations to settle in terms of column widths.
- [`supertabular`](//ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) is a predecessor of `longtable` and remains in (not obsolete) since it provides a alternative syntax.
- [`tabu`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabu) attempts to provide support for all of the aforementioned structures but through a new interface/syntax.
- `longtabu` - also provided by the `tabu` package, is a `longtable` version of the `tabu` table.
- [`ltxtable`](//ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) pro­vides the func­tion­al­ity of `longtable` and `tab­u­larx` to­gether in­side a `longtable` en­vi­ron­ment.
- [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) defines a new set of horizontal lines for use in `array` and `tabular` environments under the premise of discarding the use of vertical lines; the columnar structure of an `array`/`tabular` necessarily lends itself to have horizontal separation between columns, so there's no need for additional (vertical) lines. In fact, the [`booktabs` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs) mentions:

  > You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times:
  >
  > 1. Never, ever use vertical rules.
  > 2. Never use double rules.

  The package aims to provide `book`-quality `tab`le`s`, hence the name `booktabs`.
- [`tabularray`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) redefines the way tables are set in code, structuring it akin to a regular document with a preamble and content. Instead of mixing code within the content like with regular tables, formatting and layout styles/options are set via key-values in the structure "preamble", thereby separating code from content, making it easier to update/change elements.

  This example is taken from the [`tabularray` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/tabularray):

  ```
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {rX},
    colsep = 8mm,
    hlines = {2pt, white},
    row{odd} = {azure8},
    row{even} = {gray8},
    row{1} = {6em,azure2,fg=white,font=\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily},
    row{2-Z} = {3em,font=\Large},
  }
    Tabularray & Typeset Tabulars and Arrays with \LaTeX3 \\
    Author & Jianrui Lyu (tolvjr@163.com) \\
    Version & \myversion\ (\the\year-\mylpad\month-\mylpad\day) \\
    Code & \url{https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray} \\
    Code & \url{https://bitbucket.org/lvjr/tabularray} \\
    Support & \url{https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions} \\
    Support & \url{https://topanswers.xyz/tex} \\
    Issue & \url{https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues} \\
  \end{tblr}
  ```

  and yields

  [image]