# How to fix this Package array Error: Only one column-spec allowed?

Tags: tables, columns

I have the following table:

[image]

From the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,tabularx,multirow}

\begin{document}
\section{Custos}

    \begin{tabular}
    {|
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{3.9cm}|} % Item
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{1.9cm}|} % Quantidade
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{3.0cm}|} % Valor, Valor
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{2.6cm}|} % Valor, Valor
    }
        \hline Item             &   Quantidade  &   Valor Unitário (R\$)    &   Valor Total (R\$) \\ \hline
        CD                      &   1           &   5,00                    &   5,00,00           \\ \hline
        Impressão               &   800         &   0,15                    &   120,00            \\ \hline
        Reserva Gerencial       &   1           &   20,00                   &   20,00             \\ \hline
        Reserva de Contingência &   1           &   20,00                   &   20,00             \\ \hline
        Total                   & \multicolumn{2}{c c|}{}                   &   165,00            \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But is throwing the error:

```
 test.tex:29: Package array Error: Only one column-spec. allowed.. [...                  & \multicolumn{2}{c c}{}]
```

The table is rendering almost as I like to, except for the shifted `|` before `165,00`.

How to remove the error from appearing and align correctly the shifted `|` pipe?

---

## Update

Nice list for references:

1. [Multi-column and multi-row cells in LaTeX tables](http://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/)
2. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables
3. [What is the difference between tabular, tabular* and tabularx environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341205/what-is-the-difference-between-tabular-tabular-and-tabularx-environments)
4. [Using multicolumn in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131867/using-multicolumn-in-latex)
5. [Latex Table multiple row and multiple column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291026/latex-table-multiple-row-and-multiple-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\multicolumn` can have only *one* column specifier. You have two! However, 
why do you have such complicated head definition. This does the same:

```
\begin{tabular}
    {|
        >{\RaggedRight}p{3.9cm}| 
        % Item
        >{\RaggedRight}p{1.9cm}|
        % Quantidade
        >{\RaggedRight}p{3.0cm}| 
        % Valor, Valor
        >{\RaggedRight}p{2.6cm}| }\hline 
    Item             &   Quantidade  &   Valor Unitário (R\$)    &   Valor 
    Total (R\$) \\ \hline
    CD                      &   1           &   5,00                    &   
    5,00,00           \\ \hline
    Impressão               &   800         &   0,15                    &   
    120,00            \\ \hline
    Reserva Gerencial       &   1           &   20,00                   &   
    20,00             \\ \hline
    Reserva de Contingência &   1           &   20,00                   &   
    20,00             \\ \hline
    Total                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &   
    165,00            \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the argument to `\multicolumn`, but I think you're taking the wrong approach to tables: there is no need to specify the width, as TeX will compute it by itself.

You can see that the first and second example are essentially the same.

I also added a third example for showing how easy it is to get alignment at the decimal comma with `siunitx`. This requires some attention in the input of the table headers, but the reward is big.

In the final example I used `booktabs` features, but they're not mandatory.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,tabularx,multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} % for the last example

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}} % for siunitx

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Original, with the fix}

    \begin{tabular}
    {|
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{3.9cm}|} % Item
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{1.9cm}|} % Quantidade
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{3.0cm}|} % Valor, Valor
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{2.6cm}|} % Valor, Valor
    }
        \hline Item             &   Quantidade  &   Valor Unitário (R\$)    &   Valor Total (R\$) \\ \hline
        CD                      &   1           &   5,00                    &   5,00              \\ \hline
        Impressão               &   800         &   0,15                    &   120,00            \\ \hline
        Reserva Gerencial       &   1           &   20,00                   &   20,00             \\ \hline
        Reserva de Contingência &   1           &   20,00                   &   20,00             \\ \hline
        Total                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &   165,00            \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Simpler}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline Item             &   Quantidade  &   Valor Unitário (R\$)    &   Valor Total (R\$) \\ \hline
        CD                      &   1           &   5,00                    &   5,00              \\ \hline
        Impressão               &   800         &   0,15                    &   120,00            \\ \hline
        Reserva Gerencial       &   1           &   20,00                   &   20,00             \\ \hline
        Reserva de Contingência &   1           &   20,00                   &   20,00             \\ \hline
        Total                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &   165,00            \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}

\end{table}


\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Better?}

\begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=2.2] S[table-format=3.2] }
\toprule
{Item}                  & {Quantidade} & {Valor Unitário (R\$)} & {Valor Total (R\$)} \\
\midrule
CD                      &   1          &    5,00                &     5,00            \\
Impressão               &   800        &    0,15                &   120,00            \\
Reserva Gerencial       &   1          &   20,00                &    20,00            \\
Reserva de Contingência &   1          &   20,00                &    20,00            \\
\midrule
Total                   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}                  &   165,00            \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]