# Horizontal stretching of pmatrix

Tags: diagrams, matrices

I have the following code to generate a pmatrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}

\begin{document}

\
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

\end{document}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to stretch the matrix both horizontally and vertically in such a way such that it covers most of the page area. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can play with `\arraycolsep`, and to ensure a proper spacing between the contents of the matrix and the parentheses, you can nest a  `matrix` environment, surrounded by a  pair of horizontal spaces, in a `pmatrix` environment, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \hspace {0.7em}
  \begin{matrix}
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 & 0
  \end{matrix}
    \hspace {0.7em}
  \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, how is that different from [Alex' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441744/121799)?

Comment: @marmot:  Oops! I didn't see his answer. Apart from a few explanations details, you'tr right, it's the same. I'll delete it in a moment.

Comment: @marmot: I've modified my code  to have a better spacing w.r.t. parentheses.

Comment: I am not a referee but must admit that I still can't see much of a difference in the code. Any chance that you were talking about nesting these things but forgot to do it in the actual code?

Comment: @marmot: Absolutely. A copy-paste accident. I've fixed it (should always re-read what I post to check…).

Comment: OK, now it was upvotable ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't post  it to be upvoted, but because I felt something wasn't correct in the spacings, and I remembered a code I used in a similar situation a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 7):

Use `\arraycolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{10pt}.
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

And also please un-learn $$, it's deprecated.

Comment: You may want to mention that the default value of `\arraycolsep` is 5pt; hence, setting this length parameter to 10pt doubles the width between the columns.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to use `tabular*`. Please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341205/121799) for more options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}

\begin{document}

\[
 \left(\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tabular*}{0.85\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{6}{c}}
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
 \end{tabular*}}}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following code requires the number of columns; it automatically fills the `\displaywidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \replicate \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{bigpmatrix}[1]
 {\left(\,
  \settowidth\dimen@{$\Bigg(\,\,$}%
  \vcenter to \displaywidth\bgroup
    \def\\{\cr\noalign{\vfil}}%
    \edef\preamble{\replicate{#1-2}{$####$\unskip&}}%
    \tabskip=0pt
    \medskip
    \halign to \dimexpr \displaywidth-2\dimen@\bgroup
      $##$\unskip\tabskip=0pt plus 1fil &
      \span\preamble
      $##$\unskip\tabskip0pt\cr
 }{\crcr\egroup\medskip\egroup\,\right)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bigpmatrix}{12}
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
 \end{bigpmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A TABstack allows both dimensions (column gap and row baselineskip) to be specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{60pt}
\setstacktabbedgap{60pt}
\parenMatrixstack{
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
 }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can use the TikZ package in the preamble and use amsmath as well. With this, use the scaling feature:

```
\usepackage{tikz} % in the preamble
\usepackage{amsmath} % in the preamble
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} % in the preamble
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
```

However, I am not sure whether you need to set `transform shape`.