specify total width of table
I want to specify the total width of this table without specifying individual column widths, is there any simple solution?
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cc}
            \toprule
            N & $E_{\pi(\theta)}[\nu(\theta)]$ & SE \\
            \midrule
            100 & 0.676 & 3.311 \\
            200 & 0.734 & 1.978 \\
            500 & 0.741 & 1.360 \\
            1000 & 0.699 & 0.956 \\
            3000 & 0.730 & 0.541 \\
            10000 & 0.719 & 0.298 \\
            50000 & 0.721 & 0.134 \\
            100000 & 0.722 & 0.095 \\
            200000 & 0.721 & 0.067 \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}


tabularx package

Also {table*}.  How do you want the extra width to be used?  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341205/107497

@Stephen how do i specify table width using it?

Have you read its documentation?@hovjr

Should all columns have the same width?

@Mico That would work as well, I just dont have time to switch to tabularx as I have many other tables to apply to. Is there a simple solution similar to how it is structured now?

@hovjr - A tabular setup does not permit you to specify an overall target width. You'll have to switch to tabularx or tabular* to gain the ability of specifying an overall target width.

Off-topic: Don't specify any vertical rules if you also wish to employ the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package.

Are you familiar with the posting How to force a table into page width? While that query is mainly concerned with a specific target width -- viz., \textwidth -- the answers also work for target widths of less than 1\textwidth.

You can use widetable (not foolproof in every situation, but with simple tables it works).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{widetable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp] % don't forget p
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{widetable}{6cm}{@{}rcc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{N} & $E_{\pi(\theta)}[\nu(\theta)]$ & SE \\
\midrule
   100 & 0.676 & 3.311 \\
   200 & 0.734 & 1.978 \\
   500 & 0.741 & 1.360 \\
  1000 & 0.699 & 0.956 \\
  3000 & 0.730 & 0.541 \\
 10000 & 0.719 & 0.298 \\
 50000 & 0.721 & 0.134 \\
100000 & 0.722 & 0.095 \\
200000 & 0.721 & 0.067 \\
\bottomrule
\end{widetable}

\caption{A fixed width table without vertical rules}

\end{table}

\end{document}


I removed the vertical rule that makes no sense with booktabs.
On the other hand, you can obtain exactly the same result with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp] % don't forget p
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{tabular*}{6cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rcc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{N} & $E_{\pi(\theta)}[\nu(\theta)]$ & SE \\
\midrule
   100 & 0.676 & 3.311 \\
   200 & 0.734 & 1.978 \\
   500 & 0.741 & 1.360 \\
  1000 & 0.699 & 0.956 \\
  3000 & 0.730 & 0.541 \\
 10000 & 0.719 & 0.298 \\
 50000 & 0.721 & 0.134 \\
100000 & 0.722 & 0.095 \\
200000 & 0.721 & 0.067 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{A fixed width table without vertical rules}

\end{table}

\end{document}

